# Wrong Github username during SSH session

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have two Github accounts - let's say `setevoy` and an `othername`.

I used both for one project, and then access for `othername` was disabled, so I have to use my main account - `setevoy`.

I my `~/.ssh.config` I have an entry for Github auth:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Host bitbucket.blabla.net                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 User blablauser                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
 IdentityFile  /home/setevoy/.ssh/setevoy_main_priv_openssh                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

Host bitbucket.org                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 IdentityFile  /home/setevoy/.ssh/setevoy_main_priv_openssh

Host github.com
  User setevoy
  IdentityFile  /home/setevoy/.ssh/setevoy_main_priv_openssh
```

Now, if I try to run `clone` for this project - I have an error:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you
>   have the correct access rights

And SSH still gives me an old, disabled, account:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com

Hi othername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

In my `setevoy` account's settings I have exactly `setevoy_main_priv_openssh` key added.

I could use project's repositories via browser under `setevoy` username and I can use my own repositories with terminal and SSH keys.

What I'm doing wrong here? Maybe I'm not aware of kind of "caching" for SSH sessions and it still trying to use old username?

Comment: Which email is configured in our repo? You can see it with `git config user.email`.

Comment: @Fralec My work email. It not used in (both) Github's accounts at all.
I tried to change `user.email` to that which used for `setevoy` account - but still have `othername` during `ssh git@github`.

Comment: Try to make a `git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`

Comment: Yeah, thanks - HTTP will work with `git clone https://setevoy@github.com/***/azure-dns.git`, but I'd like to use SSH instead :-| And I have a bunch of already downloaded/used repositories on my laptop - don't want to change each `config` to HTTPS instead of SSH.

Comment: This? `git clone ssh://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git`

Comment: @Fralec Thanks for replies :-) And this return "Permission denied (publickey)".

Comment: You have correctly configured your keys I think?

Comment: I think so - I used them last few months on this project (before my second account was detached from project's repo).

Comment: Indeed - `ssh-add ~/.ssh/setevoy_main_priv_openssh` solved issue.